# Tracing an object

Tags: c#, .net

Suppose I want an object with a list of strings and every method that this object gets passed to adds its name to the list of strings. Basically it's a stack trace, except unlike a stack trace it keeps a record of everywhere it's previously been.

In order to do this, I would have to put code in every method it goes through to add itself but if it went through methods that didn't know to add themselves then of course it wouldn't have a record of having been through those methods.

It would be cool if it were possible to make an object self aware, so to speak, of the methods it goes through but I don't think it is. But I'm wondering if there is any other way to get a record of all methods the object goes through, including those methods that don't know to update the object?

EDIT: Currently, I'm thinking the closest you could come to solving this would be to make any property/method that's accessed on the object update itself at that point in time. of course this wouldn't catch places that it simply passes through without being accessed.

Comment: You start delving into [aspect oriented programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288717(v=vs.71).aspx) as you go down that path.

Comment: I expect that you can do Aspect Oriented Programming trickery to get that working, but I don't know of any pre-built utility to provide this. I also can't think of a scenario where I would want to. Either I know where the object goes, or I don't and need to clean things up.

Comment: This sounds like something that should be the debugger's job.

Comment: @MichaelT I know you could use PostSharp to cascade an aspect over all the methods in a class... but what if you don't have access to that class; or don't know what all classes you should apply it to in the first place?

Comment: @Telastyn I don't disagree, though I would suggest this isn't always possible. And furthermore, I would suggest that just because you don't 'need' this kind of a feature, if it were available it could save you time and money. The time and effort it takes to refactor some code is not reasonable and definitely not cost effecient, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @Doval A debugger will only tell you the current stack trace; not the previous places an object has been. A debugger is also not of much use in the production environment where you have to rely on logging.

Comment: @BVernon I'm not a C# person at all (Java) so specific C# frameworks are outside of my knowledge. I do recognize what you are trying to do is similar to the AOP ideals of a cross cutting concern. How that is done with a particular framework in C#, I don't know. I personally find AOP to lead to more difficult to work with code in many cases unless it is architected *very* well and wonder if you have an XY problem of sorts here (you've got an idea of what you want to implement, but don't describe the problem that is leading you to this idea). At this point, all I can do is say 'AOP might work'

Comment: @MichaelT Fair enough. I think, ultimately, the answer to my question may be that it can't be done. But I had to ask :)

Comment: @BVernon - sure, but I'm not sure how this functionality would make my refactoring cheaper. I don't need to know the _path_ an object takes, all I need to know is where it is used. Find All References already does that for me.

Comment: @Telastyn Well it certainly sounds like you wouldn't have any use for this sort of thing then, doesn't it? :)

Comment: @BVernon - to extrapolate, I don't expect you don't have any use for this sort of thing either - especially relative to the cost of implementing it (if there isn't an existing tool to supply such functionality).

Comment: @Telastyn Yes, I understand exactly what you're trying to say. My last response was meant to be read as "I don't feel like arguing with you so let's just agree to disagree".

Comment: Exactly why do you want to do this?

Comment: @StefanHanke The thing that started the idea for me was tracking usage statistics. Another benefit would be for debugging. Many people's reaction to this seems to be "There are other ways to do this so why would you need to do it this way?" I think that sort of thinking is pretty short sighted. However, it does seem to be impossible to implement (even with reflection and AOP). The fact it's impossible to implement doesn't mean it wouldn't be very useful though if you could implement it.

Comment: Have a look at the profiler APIs, e.g. [No Code Can Hide from the Profiling API in the .NET Framework 2.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300553.aspx). For understanding purposes you could just profile some tests to get a feel for it.

Answer (score 1):

I would investigate non-coding solutions first:

1. [ReSharper - Find Usages](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp80/Navigation_and_Search__Finding_Usages__Finding_Usages_of_a_Symbol.html)
2. [Visual Studio Ultimate - Map Dependencies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj739835.aspx)

Comment: Doxygen will map your dependancies, callers and callees and unlike VS Ultimate, its free.

Comment: @gbjbaanb sure, there is more than one tool for doing this.

Comment: I only mentioned it as Ultimate is very, very.. very expensive.

Comment: Thanks... finding usages isn't really a problem though. The idea isn't so much about knowing where all a 'class' is used so much as knowing where a specific 'instance of an object' has actually been. This way, in a production environment where you can't use the aforementioned tools, you would be able to give really, really great logging information for both exceptions and usage stats.

Comment: @BVernon you must have a very specific codebase to deal with. I guess AOP-style magic is the way to go.

Comment: @BVernon Could you update your question to clarify why you need to trace individual objects/instances rather than the class as a whole? That would make the question much more interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `StackTrace` and `StackFrame` objects in the `System.Diagnostics` namespace.  They may be able to help log out information that is desired.  When an exception occurs the stack trace in the exception is captured in a similar manner.  It sounds like you want to log non-exception situations as well, so this may help as one can get the stack and frame at any point in the code.